# Meaning of "what would they know about the end of everything?"

Tags: phrase-meaning, literature

> In the car I was lonely and scared. I let out a couple of dry sobs. On
> either side of the freeway, the lights of new industrial parks were flicking
> on. I wound the window down and punched the radio button. Cat Empire:
> ‘Nights Like These’. Once I had overheard a spiteful girl dismiss that band
> as just a bunch of private schoolboys: **what would they know about the end
> of everything?** But the clattering percussion. Those horns, the creamy
> thread of trumpet. I cranked it up and began to yell the words. I’m alive, I’m
> alive, I’m alive, I’m alive, I’m aliiiiiiiive…

Does it mean "what would they know about the end
of world?"

Source: *The Spare Room* by *Helen Garner*

Comment: Have you listened to the song? What's it about? (Questions like this, which is about the meaning of a song and a story, might do better on Literature SE, but as always show your research.)

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Yes you are right. But it is a little confusing. I should ask it on Literature SE and I should add my research but I do not expect negative point...

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused here. I think the song is called "Days Like These".

Regarding your question. It depends what you mean with "everything". The book is about a cancer patient told from the view of her friend letting her stay in her spare room. My guess is that the "end of everything" refers to the end of her life, because for the dying person everything ends.

I do not have the book though to refer to the paragraph in context.